# Removing span tags issue if text has encoded characters

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm looking to remove span tags that wrap blocks of text in an in-browser editor but am having trouble if the text contains any sort of special characters like newline '\n' or encoded characters like   , • , etc.

Here's my code that works on sentences without encoded characters

```
function fnIgnoreThisErr(evtTargID){    
    // use the passed parameter 
    var errIdx = evtTargID.substr(evtTargID.indexOf('err-') + 4);  
    // buld span tag for finding
    var errSpan = "span.err-" + evtTargID;
    // declare the editor
    var editor = CKEDITOR.instances.editor1;
    // get text from the editor
    var edata = editor.getData();  
    // find the specific span in the text
    var spanData = $( edata ).find(errSpan); 
    // get outerHTML and innerText to use for replacement
    var myCurrText = spanData[0].outerHTML;
    var myNewText = spanData[0].innerHTML;
    // standard js replace works if no special chars
    var replace_text = edata.replace(myCurrText, myNewText);  //
    // sets the data back in CKEditor
    editor.setData(replace_text);
}
```

Here's an example of the text with the span tag
myCurrText:

```
<span class=\"vts-warn vts-ParseFailure err-2\">Approval of ICA<br />\n&nbsp; GAMA requested further clarification of proposed &sect;&sect;25.1739 (now &sect;25.1729) and 25.1805(b) (now &sect;26.11(b)) requirements that ICA prepared in accordance with paragraph H.</span>
```

And with the span tag removed.

```
Approval of ICA<br />\n&nbsp; GAMA requested further clarification of proposed &sect;&sect;25.1739 (now &sect;25.1729) and 25.1805(b) (now &sect;26.11(b)) requirements that ICA prepared in accordance with paragraph H.
```

It works great on plain sentences without any encoded characters. I can switch to jQuery but couldn't get replaceWith to work either.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Can you add the console output?

Comment: You can try `$('span').contents().unwrap();`

Comment: I tried '$( edata ).find("span.err-2").contents().unwrap().end().end().html();  which' only seems to return the first sentence in the editor not the actual content of errSpan. But I do get an interesting object back that I may be able to work with.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. There appears to be a discrepancy between html entities and the way they are being rendered/interpreted by the browser and my JS.
i.e. The outerHTML of the span is not a character-for-character match of the text in edata.

So I just get the indexOf value for the start of the span and the length of the span node. However, due to the discrepancy mentioned, this length may include additional characters. So, next, I find the exact position of the '' tag. From there, I build a string variable that exactly matches the text that needs to be replaced.

Here's my final code. (I kept it long-form for clarity)

```
function fnIgnoreThisErr(evtTargID){    
    // use the passed parameter 
    var errIdx = evtTargID.substr(evtTargID.indexOf('err-') + 4);  
    // buld span tag for finding
    var errSpan = "span.err-" + evtTargID;
    // declare the editor
    var editor = CKEDITOR.instances.editor1;
    // get text from the editor
    var edata = editor.getData();  
    // find the specific span in the text
    var spanData = $( edata ).find(errSpan); 
    // extract the span class name
    var spanTag = '<span class="'+spanData[0].className+'">'
    // find indexOf value for the span opening tag
    var spanPos = edata.indexOf(spanTag);
    // get the initial length of the span.
    var spanLength = spanData[0].outerHTML.length;
    // get the actual text from that span length.
    var spanString = edata.substring(spanPos,spanPos+spanLength);
    // find the acutal position of the span closing tag
    var spanClose = spanString.indexOf('</span>');
    var spanTagClosePos = spanClose+7;
    // extract the true text comprising the span tag
    var spanStringMod = edata.substring(spanPos,spanPos+spanTagClosePos);
    var spanInnerHtm = spanData[0].innerHTML;
    log("errSpan: "+ errSpan);
    log("errSpanClass: "+ errSpanClass);
    log("spanData: "+  JSON.stringify(spanData));
    log("spanPos: "+ spanPos);
    log("spanTagClosePos: "+ spanTagClosePos);
    log("spanStringMod: "+ spanStringMod);
    log("spanInnerHtm: "+ spanInnerHtm);
    var newEdata = edata.replace(spanStringMod, spanInnerHtm);  
    log(" newEdata: "+ newEdata);   
    // update the editor
    editor.setData(newEdata);
}
```

I hope this helps someone, somewhere, at some time!

Cheers!